# Node configuration file in development mode

Tags: node.js, configuration-files, strapi

I have a live website which is deployed in development mode. The website is running on Nodejs through Strapi CMS.

In order to get an SSL certificate I'm required to find the server configuration file, but since the website is in development mode I'm having a hard time finding it.

Is there a configuration file for Nodejs also in development mode by default?
Can it be different in the backend runs on Strapi CMS?

Comment: The config would be specific for strapi, if it exists. node just provides [an api](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_server) to manage a https server

Comment: Looks like you can [inject tls middleware](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/171) into strapi